# how to I convert a string with format "YYYY/MM/DD" into NSDate type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm receiving a string with a date in the format `yyyy/mm/dd` and I was wondering how could I convert that into `NSDate` type so I can subtract days out of the date?

Comment: samo, samo, samo...  Boring, boring, boring...  I hope I'm not the only who is fed up with the same topic once or twice a day.  Silly people who don't bother to run a search are here and there, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to an `NSDate` using the `NSDateFormatter`.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];

NSdate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012/03/17"];
```

Be aware that allocating an `NSDateFormatter` is a pretty heavy task so if you are parsing a lot of dates then allocate it once and keep it around :)